# LFTP active mode with servers that do not recognize the PORT command

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, lftp

I am using LFTP to transfer files from a server, which unfortunately does not recognize the PORT command. I do not have control over the server (do not know in detail what server is) and I have to use the active mode.

This is the command line as:

```
lftp -e 'debug 10;set ftp:passive-mode off; set ftp:auto-passive-mode no; ls; bye;' -u user,password ftp://ftp.site.com
```

This is the debug output:

```
<--- 200 Using default language en_US
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 UTF8 set to on           
---> OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
<--- 200 OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
---> USER xxxxx
<--- 331 Password required for xxxxx
---> PASS xxxxxx
<--- 230 User xxxxx logged in     
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ 0 successful               
---> PROT P
<--- 200 Protection set to Private       
---> PORT 172,16,133,11,146,168
<--- 500 Illegal PORT command                    
---> LIST
---> ABOR
---- Closing aborted data socket
---- Chiusura del socket di controllo
```

It seems that LFTP renounces to connect to data socket because the remote server does not support the PORT command. Is there a way to convince LFTP can still connect to port 20? By FTP manual obviously no problem.

Answer (score 8):

The issue, I think, is not that the FTP server doesn't support the `PORT` command (it does), but rather, it doesn't like the IP address/port that your FTP client is sending in the `PORT` command.

```
PORT 172,16,133,11,146,168
```

...tells the server to connect to address 172.16.133.11, port 37544*.  The interesting part here is the IP address: it's an RFC 1918 address (*i.e.* it's a [private network address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)).  That, in turn, suggests that your FTP client is in a LAN somewhere, and is connecting to an FTP server using a *public* IP address.

That remote FTP server *cannot* connect to a private network address; by definition, RFC 1918 address are not publicly routable.

Thus it very well could be that the FTP server is trying to make a connection to the address/port given in your `PORT` command, fails, thus that is why the FTP server fails the command, saying:

```
500 Illegal PORT command
```

To make a `PORT` command work with that FTP server, you would need to discover the *public* IP address that that server can connect to, to reach your client machine.  Let's say that this address is `1.2.3.4`.  Then you would need to tell `lftp` to use that address in its `PORT` command, using the `ftp:port-ipv4` option.

Chances are, though, that public IP address is the address of a NAT/router/firewall, *and* that that NAT/router/firewall will not allow connections, from the outside world to a high numbered port (*e.g.* 37544), to be routed to a machine within the LAN.  This is one of the issues with *active* FTP data transfers, *i.e.* FTP data transfers which use the `PORT` (or `EPRT`) commands: they are not considered "firewall-friendly".

Hope this helps!

---

* - why `146,168` translates to port 37544?

According to FTP's [RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) those parameters are:

> (...) 16-bit TCP port address. This address information is broken into
> 8-bit fields and the value of each field is transmitted as a decimal
> number (in character string representation).

```
146 dec = 10010010 bin = A
168 dec = 10101000 bin = B

    A        B
10010010 10101000 bin = 37544 dec
```